# PHP function can not be called

Tags: php

I have a link in page A that directs to page B. page B has a function like this:

```
function s(){
    $_SESSION['active']='0';
}
s();
echo $_SESSION['active'];
```

The problem is that in order for  function s() to be called and `$_SESSION['active']` be set, I need a second refresh, and this adds some overhead. I don't know why this function is not called when directing from page  A to B? any help would be appreciated.

EDIT 1: I have session_start(); at the very top of every php script. the only solution I could come up with is a second refresh

EDIT 2: I have inspected the code very carefully, echoing every variable in my function and also using XDEBUG. the problem is as I stated, when directing to page B the function is not called until I refresh the page.

EDIT 3: Problem solved. it was a very stupid mistake, that session variable was unset somewhere in the code preceding that function. that problematic function was part of nested functions, and I am using circular references in number of functions which makes my code hard to read, That is why I could't post here. Thanks ever one, it is really a shame.

Comment: add `session_start();` before your code

Comment: did you started session?

Comment: yeah yeah I did

Comment: Did you started session before...??

Comment: Can you show more code?

Answer (score 1):

```
function s(){
$_SESSION['active']='0';
 return $_SESSION['active'];
}
$result =s();
echo $result;
```

Try this as there is no return from the function

Comment: Could you please add more details ? code only answers are not that helpful.

Comment: Hey downvoter give reason before downvote. So that i can understand where i am wrong

Comment: Himal - the problematical function contains a bunch of nested functions and includes which makes it hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of choices.  One could move the session code to page A so that when it redirects to B, one could see the updated session value.  Or, you could try something like this on page B:

```
<?php
session_start();
function s(){
    $_SESSION['active']='0';
}
s();
session_write_close()
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['active'];
```

See [demo](https://3v4l.org/LPSl2).

You may wish to review a related discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19471979/if-i-use-session-start-in-function-it-starts-session-but-doesnt-output-sessions).

Note, however, that when I ran this code:

```
<?php
session_start();

function s(){
   $_SESSION['active']='0';
}
s();
echo $_SESSION['active'];
```

at [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/CksZ3#output) it ran fine with PHP 5.2.3-5.6.30 and 7.0.0-7.2.0beta1.  If one is using PHP 4 or an earlier version of PHP 5, the function does execute, but the result comes with warnings.